# What's the font on the table in the movie Casino Royale?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: table]

I'm looking for the font used on this table or one similar to it.

Comment: Hi HellspawnedJawa! Your question might be closed as incomplete. We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366/8708) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That font is one of the [Benguiat](http://www.myfonts.com/search/benguiat/)s:

[image]